Edit toolbar menu
When making a SwiftUI editable toolbar like this, there is a small menu with an Edit toolbar button. How can I add items and controls to this menu?
Here's a small example:
.toolbar(id: "options") {
    ToolbarItem(id: "A", placement: .secondaryAction) {
        Text("A")
    }
    ToolbarItem(id: "B", placement: .secondaryAction) {
        Text("B")
    }
    ToolbarItem(id: "C", placement: .secondaryAction) {
        Text("C")
    }
}
.toolbarRole(.editor)

Note that in order to display the toolbar you have to put it in a navigationStack.
